# animate div to li element jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, jquery-animate

Hello to everyone I do not understanding how can I animate "div" to "li" element
I have got horizontal list and I need to animate my arrow to clicked element.

```
<ul class="tabs-titles">
    <li><a href="#tab-1">best <br/> gifts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">best <br/> gifts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">best <br/> for gifts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-4">best <br/> gifts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-5">best <br/> gifts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-6">best <br/> gifts <br/> gifts</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="active-tab"></div>
```

here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9E2WQ/3/).

Comment: For one thing, you can only use parent positioning if the element has a parent. You have your active tab div outside of your list, therefore the list is not the parent of the div. Start there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/9E2WQ/5/

This works. Take a look to my edits.
You have to use `$(this).position().top + $(this).height()/2` instead of `parent.height()` to get the arrow move.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

As I see that @Kevin has posted a very good answer, I suggest you use his, however, for completeness, I'll post another approach. Note that it is not perfect and would require some fine tuning to fit any final situation, but it will work.

This'll get the job done:

http://jsfiddle.net/9E2WQ/9/

By using the base height and the number of the tab, you can determine the proper height for each of the links. The only thing you may have to watch out for is:

```
var dist = 22 + (num-1)*($(this).height()+(parseInt($(this).css("marginTop"))*2));
```

This requires all of the links to be the same height. If you want any of the links to be a different height, you will need a different way to calculate the distance from the top of the div.

Comment: Nice! It's ceirtainly more accurate in calculation! But, as you said, if he adds one li he must update the js code. Isn't this annoying? I would expect that my code will work in any situation.

Comment: Thx you so much guys! Yes Kevin's decision is more suitable for me, and it works fine. But your answer is really helpfull too. thanks again!

Comment: @KevinCittadini In theory, no. Adding another li would not pose a problem to this code, *as long as all of the li's are the same height*